# TestCafe how to check field value

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to write a test using testcafe framework which checks if field has expected value. For REST responses I am using RequestLogger, but I have no idea how to check if one of the UI field has expected value.

Any ideas?

I would like to check if this field has marked value

Comment: Have you looked at TestCafe's official doc? https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: Yes, but since I am still very new to automated tests I am not sure how should I do that. Any paragraph or hint what to use for that? First reply wasn't really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample:

```
const errorMsg = Selector('.alert.alert-error').innerText
await t.expect(errorMsg).contains("Login and/or password are wrong.")
```

Another approach:

```
if(await Selector('div').withText('testee@tester.com').exists)
    {
        console.log("PASS")
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("FAIL")
    }
```